# Prefix all spark dataframe columns except primary key column

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Below is the code i have for prefixing column names. I want to exclude one or multiple primary key columns. My primaryKeys is a string array which may contain 1 or more primary key fields.

```
val primaryKeys = args(2).split("-")

val prefix = "w1."
val renamedColumns = df.columns.map(c=> df(c).as(s"$prefix$c"))
val dfNew = df.select(renamedColumns: _*)

val prefix2 = "w2."
val renamedColumns2 = df2.columns.map(c2=> df2(c2).as(s"$prefix2$c2"))
val df2New = df2.select(renamedColumns2: _*)

If it is just one column i was able to rename using withColumnRenamed but i am unable to do it if i have multiple primary columns.
```

I am unable to do something like this

```
for (primaryKey <- primaryKeys) {
 dfNew.withColumnRenamed("$PREFIX1"+s"${primaryKey}",s"$primaryKey").toDF()
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can conditionally assemble `renamedColumns` to prefix only the non-primary-key columns as follows:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1", "a", "c1", "d1"),
  ("2", "b", "c2", "d2"),
  ("3", "c", "c3", "d3")
).toDF("pk1", "pk2", "col1", "col2")

val primaryKeys = Array("pk1", "pk2")
val prefix = "w1."

val renamedColumns = df.columns.map(
  c => if ( primaryKeys contains c ) df(c).as(c) else df(c).as(s"$prefix$c")
)

val dfNew = df.select(renamedColumns: _*)

dfNew.show
+---+---+-------+-------+
|pk1|pk2|w1.col1|w1.col2|
+---+---+-------+-------+
|  1|  a|     c1|     d1|
|  2|  b|     c2|     d2|
|  3|  c|     c3|     d3|
+---+---+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. I am a java developer and new to scala. My thinking goes more in the way how java works . It is difficult to find these kind of solutions anywhere unless a question is posted in here. Can you suggest any book or course that could help me solve these?

Comment: One of the Scala books I would recommend is `Programming in Scala` by `Martin Odersky`, et al.  Odersky is the author of Scala.